# socketio4net error initializing handshake

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, bitcoin, socketio4net

I'm using Xamarin(mono 3.2.5) on OSX to create a C# console app that connects to the blockchain.info websocket stream. I've included the socketio4net library from NuGet and thought I followed the specs correctly, but I'm a bit new to socket.io connections in general, so please correct me on what I'm doing wrong. I get an error immediately after calling the socket.Connect() method below.

I have created a few event handlers like so:

```
static void SocketOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine ("opened event handler");
    Console.WriteLine (e.ToString());
}

static void SocketError(object sender, SocketIOClient.ErrorEventArgs e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine ("error event handler");
    Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
}

static void SocketMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine ("message event handler");
    Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
}
```

and my code is as follows:

```
var socket = new Client (@"ws://ws.blockchain.info:8335/inv");
socket.Opened += SocketOpened;
socket.Error += SocketError;
socket.Message += SocketMessage;

socket.Connect ();
Console.WriteLine ("handshake: " + socket.HandShake.ErrorMessage);

socket.On("connect", (fn) => {
    Console.WriteLine("On.connect msg: " + fn.MessageText);
});

socket.On ("open", (fn) => {
    Console.WriteLine("On.open msg: " + fn.MessageText);
});
```

my console output from this:

```
error event handler
Error initializing handshake with ws://ws.blockchain.info:8335/inv
handshake: Error getting handsake from Socket.IO host instance: An error occurred performing a WebClient request.
```

What have I done incorrectly? The blockchain API documentation is here: https://blockchain.info/api/api_websocket  and I've tried both URLs they specify. Omitting the port number  in the URL generates a different error. Instead of "error performing WebClient request", it appears to hunt for a local path to the socket server, which clearly is incorrect.

Any help from a more experienced programmer would be much appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem, did you fix it?

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, on my case, its because of default internet connection at office must go through proxy.

Simply set the proxy to none with the code below, solved my problem.

System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;